# wordpress page can't be found, wordpress is installed in the sub directory

Tags: wordpress

My Wordpress URL:

```
mydomain.com/blog
```

My Site URL:

```
 mydomain.com
```

index.php and .htaccess files is in blog folder.

blog/index.php

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

blog/htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

blog/wp-config.php

```
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

when i am access to my page mydomain.com/blog/index.php   it shows the page can't be found error.how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You htaccess code should be

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```